# Insert csv file to PostgreSQL from JMETER

Tags: postgresql, jmeter

I'm using JMeter for API testing. And i need to insert summary csv file into PostgreSQL from JMeter. So i don't find right query to insert csv into PostgreSQL. Any idea for that.

Thanks.

Comment: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download [PostgreSQL JDBC Driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/) and drop it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Add [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to a Thread Group and configure it to read the values from your CSV file
4. Add [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) and put your database URL and credentials there
5. Add [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler and configure it to issue SQL [Insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html) statement with the values from the CSV file:

   [image]

Just make sure to provide enough threads or loops in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) so all the values from the CSV could be processed